# Python pywin32 : in outlook how to mark an email as "Complete"

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

with the help of pywin32 I can read an email and mark it as read :

```
message.Unread = False
```

but I want to mark it as "Complete".

I tried to use :

```
message.FlagRequest = "Complete"
```

but didn't work either

Can someone help to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out how to mark an email as complete.
There is a method : `MarkAsTask(MarkInterval)` which Marks a MailItem object as a task and assigns a task interval for the object. "MarkInterval" is of datatype `OlMarkInterval` and is an enumeration :

```
olMarkComplete  5   Mark the task as complete.
olMarkNextWeek  3   Mark the task due next week.
olMarkNoDate    4   Mark the task due with no date.
olMarkThisWeek  2   Mark the task due this week.
olMarkToday     0   Mark the task due today.
olMarkTomorrow  1   Mark the task due tomorrow.
```

so for my example I just have to apply the method with interval to my email :

```
message.MarkAsTask(olMarkComplete)
```